# set background color for specific text in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

        <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#something:contains(yellow)").css("background-color", "yellow");
        });
       </script>
        </head>


        <body>
            <div id="something">

            Color it with yellow
                <div>
                    Nothing to do with it
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I want to set background-color as yellow only "Color it with yellow" text not "Nothing to do with it" but my code doing to whole div because id contain please suggest how to set color in my text "Color it with yellow"

Comment: Wrap the line with other element, like the second is wrapped in `div`.

Comment: The first problem that you have here is that you are not wrapping your text in any appropriate tags. Put `<p>` tags around your text at the very least. This way you would also be able to style the specific paragraphs with your desired colors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using `nodeType===3` which gives you div text and [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap) to make it yellow

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#something').contents().filter(function () {
         return this.nodeType === 3;
    }).wrap('<span class="yellow">');
});
```

```css
.yellow{background-color:yellow}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="something">
  Color it with yellow
  <div>
    Nothing to do with it
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#something:contains(yellow)").css("background-color", "yellow");
     });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">     </script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="something">
        Color it with yellow
      </div>
  
      <div>
        Nothing to do with it
      </div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

You have to **place** your **code** in div **container** like this it will work

Answer (score 0):

**Wrap everything in '< p >'tag. and use following code. it'll check the text with yellow color and then applies css to it as per your requirement.**

```
   function hexc(colorval) {
        var parts = colorval.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
        delete(parts[0]);
        for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
            parts[i] = parseInt(parts[i]).toString(16);
            if (parts[i].length == 1) parts[i] = '0' + parts[i];
        }
        color = '#' + parts.join('');

        return color;
    }
    var checkcolor = hexc($('p').css("color") );
    if( checkcolor == '#ffff00' ){
        $('p').css("background-color", "yellow");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p:contains(yellow)").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="something">

    <p>Color it with yellow </p>

  <p>
    Nothing to do with it
  </p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Removed `<div></div>` with `<p></p>` or you can place div with another id.

```
$("#anotherId:contains(yellow)").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Answer (score 0):

So set other color not id something div

```
 $("div:contains(yellow)").css("background-color", "yellow");
 $("div:not(#something)").css("background-color", "#fff");
```